# Converting JSON to Parquet in Amazon EMR

Tags: apache-spark, emr

I need to achieve the following, and am having difficulty coming up with an approach to accomplish it due to my inexperience with Spark:

- **Read data from .json.gz files stored in S3.**

  - Each file includes a partial day of Google Analytics data with the schema as specified in https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en.
  - File names are in the pattern ga_sessions_20170101_Part000000000000_TX.json.gz where 20170101 is a YYYYMMDD date specification and 000000000000 is an incremental counter when there are multiple files for a single day (which is usually the case).
  - An entire day of data is therefore composed of multiple files with incremental "part numbers".
  - There are generally 3 to 5 files per day.
  - All fields in the JSON files are stored with qoute (") delimiters, regardless of the data type specified in the aforementioned schema documentation. The data frame which results from reading the files (via sqlContext.read.json) therefore has every field typed as string, even though some are actually integer, boolean, or other data types.
- **Convert the all-string data frame to a properly typed data frame according to the schema specification.**

  - My goal is to have the data frame typed properly so that when it is saved in Parquet format the data types are correct.
  - Not all fields in the schema specification are present in every input file, or even every day's worth of input files (the schema may have changed over time). The conversion will therefore need to be dynamic, converting the data types of only the fields actually present in the data frame.
- **Write the data in the properly typed data frame back to S3 in Parquet format.**

  - The data should be partitioned by day, with each partition stored in a separate folder named "partition_date=YYYYMMDD" where "YYYYMMDD" is the actual date associated with the data (from the original input file names).
  - I don't think the number of files per day matters. The goal is simply to have partitioned Parquet format data that I can point Spectrum at.

I have been able to read and write the data successfully, but have been unsuccessful with several aspects of the overall task:

- I don't know how to approach the problem to ensure that I'm effectively utilizing the AWS EMR cluster to its full potential for parallel/distributed processing, either in reading, converting, or writing the data. I would like to size up the cluster as needed to accomplish the task within whatever time frame I choose (within reason).
- I don't know how to best accomplish the data type conversion. Not knowing which fields will or will not be present in any particular batch of input files requires dynamic code to retype the data frame. I also want to make sure this task is distributed effectively and isn't done inefficiently (I'm concerned about creating a new data frame as each field is retyped).
- I don't understand how to manage partitioning of the data appropriately.

Any help working through an overall approach would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input JSONs have fixed schema you can specify DF schema manually, stating fields as optional. Refer to the official [guide](http://Specify%20schema%20manually,%20stating%20fields%20as%20optional.%20Re).
If you have all values inside "", you can read them as strings and later cast to required type.

> I don't know how to approach the problem to ensure that I'm effectively...

Use Dataframe API to read input, most likely defaults will be good for this task. If you hit performance issue, attach Spark Job Timeline.

> I don't know how to best accomplish the data type conversion...

Use cast `column.cast(DataType)` method.

For example, you have 2 JSONs:

> {"foo":"firstVal"}{"foo":"val","bar" : "1"}

And you want to read 'foo' as String and bar as integer you can write something like this:

```
  val schema = StructType(
    StructField("foo", StringType, true) ::
      StructField("bar", StringType, true) :: Nil
  )
  val df = session.read
    .format("json").option("path", s"${yourPath}")
    .schema(schema)
    .load()

  val withCast = df.select('foo, 'bar cast IntegerType)
  withCast.show()
  withCast.write.format("parquet").save(s"${outputPath}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. You've addressed several aspects of my post and helped me make some progress. I did put too much into one question though, so I'm going to post separate questions for my remaining issues.